# Scaling entire iPad app to fit status bar

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've been searching SO and Google for a while now with no luck. 
What I need to do, is in certain conditions, display a status bar at the top of my application.
When this bar shows, I need to shrink all the other content down so everything still fits on the screen.

I know I can use CGAffineTransformScale, however, I am not having any luck doing it globally for the entire app.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious. Guess my lack of experience is showing.

Thanks

**EDIT:** The 'status' bar I'm referring to is NOT the standard iOS status bar. It is a custom status bar that appears only in certain conditions and sits at the top of the app.

Answer (score 0):

I would check your autolayout settings on the first view you added to the controller - if you have them setup correctly then it should resize automatically.

Comment: Ah thank you!
I'm going to look into this over the next day or so, and then I'll come back and accept.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a UIViewController or any concrete subclass of that, its view should automatically adapt to whether or not the status bar is currently visible.
Now in case you use autoresizing masks, your UI should be fine. Same should apply if you use a UIScrollView.

Comment: Hmm. I think I may have miscommunicated.
This isn't the standard iOS status bar, this is just a custom error bar that appears at the top of the app.

Comment: Then you can still have your main view (full screen) containing an `errorBar` and a `contentView`. In your layout logic, when you give `errorBar` a non-zero `frame`, increase `contentView`'s origin.y by ? pixels and decrease its height by ? pixels with ? being the `errorBar`'s height.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively: In Interface Builder, select your view controller and on the attributes inspector turn off Layout: Wants Full Screen. Then, your layout will automatically adjust its size to make room for the navigation bar.

Comment: Thanks, I will investigate that as well and accept whichever answer worked.